# document.innerHTML undefined in 'DOMNodeInserted' event catch function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am developing a chrome extension for which I have a function `addToPage()` which adds a div with class `xyz` to the loaded page. Now when the page is changed by some action (not by reload) the div added by me is being deleted and so i need to call the `addToPage()` function again so as to add it to the page. For this I used...

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
 console.log(document.innerHTML); // printing undefined
  if(document.innerHTML.indexOf("xyz") === -1){  // checking if div already present
           console.log("Chanign.............");
           addToPage();
       }
}):
```

But the problem is even `document.innerHTML` is undefined inside the event catcher.
Is there any other better way to call my function  `addToPage()` to add the div to page when ever the page changes..?

Comment: use: `document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: Bear in mind that this DOM Event is deprecated as per the warning [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)** in jquery

```
if($(".xyz").length){
              // div is not there  if $(".xyz").length=0
 }
```

Comment: are u sure we can use this inside $(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {....?

Comment: Yes. you can check there